# mvn can't resolve parent pom from remote repository

Tags: java, maven

I have a big old project which looks like

```
 main_pom
 |
 |_ module_1 \
 |_ module_2 -|--- parent_pom_1
 |_ module_3 /  
 |
 |_module_4 \
 |_module_5 -|--- parent_pom_2
 |_module_6 /
```

So when I got project first time, I was also provided by parent_pom_1 and parent_pom_2 which I install separate "by hands".
I have created a apache archiva maven repository, where I deployed my artifacts, and parent_poms.

Main_pom looks like:

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>some_group</groupId>
  <artifactId>main_pom</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group_id_of_parent_pom_1</groupId>
      <artifactId>parent_pom_1</artifactId>
      <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group_id_of_parent_pom_2</groupId>
      <artifactId>parent_pom_2</artifactId>
      <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
  <modules>
    <module>modules/module_1</module>
    <module>modules/module_2</module>
    <module>modules/module_3</module>
    <module>modules/module_4</module>
    <module>modules/module_5</module>
    <module>modules/module_6</module>

  </modules>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>my_repo_id</id>
      <name>my_repo_name</name>
      <url>my_repo_url</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>my_repo_id</id>
      <name>my_repo_name</name>
      <url>my_repo_url</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

And when I go to main_pom folder and do

> mvn install

have next erorrs:

```
[ERROR]  The build could not read 20 projects -> [Help 1] [ERROR] The project module_1-pom:10.0.1-SNAPSHOT has 1 error [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for module_1-pom::10.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact parent_pom_1:pom:10.0.1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 11 -> [Help 2]
```

As far as I understand - maven doesn't download and install parent_poms first.

How could I configure maven to work this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project has several issues. First the structure is not a good idea. Better go the following:

```
main_pom
 +- pom.xml
 |
 +-- parent-pom_1 (parent: main_pom)
      +-- pom.xml
      |_ module_1
      |_ module_2
      |_ module_3
 +-- parent-pom_2 (parent:main_pom)
     |_module_4 
     |_module_5 
     |_module_6
```

that means you don't need to install the parent pom's manually...You can start from root simply by using:

```
mvn clean package
```

No need for `mvn clean install`...

Furthermore usage of [`LATEST` as version is deprecated and should not be used anymore](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.2/release-notes.html). And defining a dependency to a parent will not help in any way..

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>group_id_of_parent_pom_1</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent_pom_1</artifactId>
  <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

Apart from the above if you use SNAPSHOT versions as parents the whole build is not reproducible..

Comment: Thanks alot for answer, but I can't change the architecture of project.
I can only refactoring existing code

Comment: You should do so otherwise this is a real technical dept and pain to handle such a project. This is also a kind of refactoring of existing code..ok the build code....